# Difficulty installing anything but Ubuntu on HP laptop, does not show GRUB once installed/updated

Tags: debian, ubuntu, fedora, system-installation

An acquaintance is attempting to install either Debian 12 or Fedora 38 on an HP laptop, but on Debian it will not boot at all after install, and on Fedora it boots but then updates break it. Ubuntu installs fine. I suspect a graphics issue. They are using an iGPU Core i7-7500U x 4 with Intel HD Graphics 620. He says that neither OS will even show a GRUB menu once installed/updated. He also says he has successfully installed Debian on other systems in the past. What is going on here?

Comment: EFI boot table is not properly updated or BIOS ignores it?

Comment: I have no idea what that means, or how to fix it.

Comment: Get into BIOS, check boot options.

Comment: He says: The HP laptop has no other options for the boot menu. You got your drive priority. Secure boot is off, UEFI is set to legacy, and some options that can’t be enabled because they’re greyed out.